# Is this correct time complexity?

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity, big-o, code-complexity

I did this as a solution to one of the leetcode problems, but I'm not sure what the complexity of my algorithm is.

```
public String countAndSay(int n) {
        if (n == 1) return "1";
        String pre = countAndSay(n-1);
        char[] prev = pre.toCharArray();
        int len = prev.length;
        if (len == 1 && prev[0] == '1') return "11";
        int idx = 1;
        int rep = 1;
        String res = "";
        while (idx <= len) {
            if (idx == len) {
                res += (Integer.toString(rep) + prev[idx-1]);
                break;
            }
            if (prev[idx-1] == prev[idx]) rep++;
            else {
                res += (Integer.toString(rep) + prev[idx-1]);
                rep = 1;
            }
            idx++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Since the recursion takes place n times and the loop is O(n), I feel like it should be O(n^2). Is that correct? If not, can you please explain why?

Comment: That is not correct, because you forgot to account for the length of the result string. In big-O, it likely classifies as _O(2^n)_.

Comment: @Andreas Let's say the length of the string is m. Why is it not O(mn)?

Comment: The method only has one input: `n`. There is no `m` input, so the formula cannot be based on `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few facts:

- The method calls itself recursively on input `n-1`.
- The method produces the  sequence known as [look-and-say sequence](https://oeis.org/A005150).
- The length of the resulting string grows exponentially with base λ, where λ = 1.303577269034... is [Conway's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence#Growth_in_length), so the length is `O(λ^n)`.
- The loop is quadratic on the length of the string (because of the repeated string concatenations), so we have `O((λ^n)^2) = O((λ^2)^n)` for the loop.

Hence we can derive the following recurrence relation:

```
T(0) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + O((λ^2)^n)
```

The asymptotic behaviour of this relation is given by

```
T(n) ∈ Θ((λ^2)^n) = Θ(1.6993^n)
```

If you use a `StringBuilder` instead of doing the evil repeated string concatenations, you can get it down to `Θ(λ^n)` which would also be asymptotically optimal for this problem.